# cordova upload video with value from textarea

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i have a problem with sending a video i captured with a value in a textarea.

i have done the video  capture.

uploading the video to the server works but the server does not receive the value from the textarea.

here is my code to upload:

```
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {

    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        inputbox = document.getElementById('inputbox').value,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        encodeURI("http://exmaple.com/api/video.php"),
        function(result) {
            alert('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
                //make sniper disappear
            var preloaderpost2 = document.getElementById('preloader-post');
            preloaderpost2.style.display = 'none';
        },
        function(error) {
            alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                //make sniper disappear
            var preloaderpost2 = document.getElementById('preloader-post');
            preloaderpost2.style.display = 'none';
        },
        { fileName: name}, {text: inputbox});

}
```

here is my php script

```
<?php
$video = time().$_FILES["file"]["name"];
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_REQUEST);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/videos/".$video);

//$fileName = $_REQUEST["fileName"];

//save data to database...

$inputbox = $_REQUEST["inputbox"];

  if(isset($video)) {
    // insert user(create Post)
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO feeds (feeds_poster_id, feeds_video, feeds_content, feeds_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                           GetSQLValueString($_SESSION["id"], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($video, "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($inputbox, "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), "date"));
      //Set post
      mysql_select_db($database_dbcon, $dbcon);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dbcon) or die(mysql_error()); 

      //Mentioned user...
  }
```

pls can someone help me A.S.P...

just want to send the video file along with the textarea value...

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the options param correctly, it should be like this: (note that fileName goes on the options, and the inputbox is a param object)

```
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {

    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
    path = mediaFile.fullPath,
    inputbox = document.getElementById('inputbox').value,
    name = mediaFile.name;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = name;
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";

    var params = {};
    params.inputbox = inputbox;

    ft.upload(path, encodeURI("http://exmaple.com/api/video.php"), function(result) {
            alert('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
                //make sniper disappear
            var preloaderpost2 = document.getElementById('preloader-post');
            preloaderpost2.style.display = 'none';
        }, function(error) {
            alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                //make sniper disappear
            var preloaderpost2 = document.getElementById('preloader-post');
            preloaderpost2.style.display = 'none';
        }, options);

}
```

Comment: do you get any error? note that the code isn't complete, that is only the part you have to change

Comment: No the page was not responding, u wrote the code isn't complete, could u help with that ?? pls...

Comment: I've updated the code, but the previous code should be enough to understand what you did wrong and how to solve